# CLARA with Gower for mixed data type

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, large-data, similarity, categorical-data

I have quite a large data (11.4 million records and 9 variables). The variables are mixed consisting of ordinal, nominal and continuous data types. Accordingly, I choose Gower method to compute dissimilarity matrix for dealing with mixed data type. However, the size of the data is too big to compute. I then find another interesting method called CLARA, which uses sample to compute clustering and then assign cluster to other points of data. The problem is that I cannot find the appropriate metric to compute distance of mixed data type. In other words, there is no Gower options in both `clara in cluster package` and `clara_medoids in ClusterR package` (This is all I can find clara in R).

Why there is no gower option in CLARA? 
What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

CLARA is described in Kaufman and Rousseeuw (1990).

The characteristics of this algorithm is that it can deal with much larger dataset because of its linear complexity in both memory and computation requirements.

Gower distance calculates a dissimilarity matrix which memory complexity is exponential O(n^2) which means that you would obtain a matrix 11.4 million rows and 11.4 million columns. Clearly not feasible.

If you want to use gower's distance, you should try to work on smaller subsamples and use a bottom-up clustering approach.

Comment: With the size of my data, I know the computation limit, so I tried to use CLARA to exploit sub-sample analysis. But how could I find an appropriate metric to deal with mixed data type? Or could you please specify which bottom-up clustering that I should further study? Thank you

Comment: Gower doesn't require the use of a distance matrix.

Comment: Time ago I faced your exact same problem. In the end I discovered ccategorical features were not relevant for my objective so I did not select them. However, a possible alternative approach was to perform hierarchical clustering starting from small sub samples. Proceed iteratively until you end up with a hierarchical clustering over clusters of clusters. However, I do not remember where I read this approach nor I implemented it

Answer (score 0):

Get the source code of CLARA.

Modify it, and add Gower distance.

Because Gower uses some data dependant normalization factors (and you can't afford to precompute a distance matrix) you'll need to integrate this directly into CLARA.

Run the modified CLARA.

Make your source code publicly available as open source, so that others don't have to do the same. It will also make it easier to extend CLARA with further distance functions in the future.

Comment: He cannot use Gower distance over tenths of millions of data

Comment: Snark is understandable, but deprecated. If you don't like it, downvote it (or leave a comment that bears the same message of "sorry, but you're asking for the moon" but in a less negative way ...)

Comment: @Seymour why? You don't need to use a distance *matrix*. Then it will scale. Just don't precompute all distances, but use the equation on the fly and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I have tried to look in the source code of CLARA but it is above my skill (my programming background is not strong). In `cluster::clara` they call `.C(cl_clara,...)` to execute Clara process and in `ClusterR::Clara_Medoids` they call another function `ClaraMedoids()` which I don't know where to look at in detail. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll definitely need to look in the C code, because of performance. R code is too slow.